# Why does a Canon MF451dw All-in-One periodically disappear off home network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, printer

Sitting here working away and the Canon MF451dw All-in-One has disappeared off the home network twice this afternoon, both times for a couple of hours.

1. The D-Link router has an IP address properly reserved for the printer. That address is statically set on the printer, and Status Monitor on the printer reports that (not a global default IP address) as the IP address even when it's invisible.
2. The printer is connecting wirelessly, and reports medium signal strength even when not appearing on the network.
3. Ping to its IP address succeeds when the printer is visible on the network (meaning visible in **Network view** in Windows Explorer) and fails when it's not. Same for attempting to connect to the printer's Remote UI.
4. DHCP lease time has been set to 240 minutes all afternoon, and since as far back as I can remember. I think that was the factory default when we upgraded the router a few years back. (I've extended this just now to 1440 minutes, and will close this question if that turns out to resolve the problem.)
5. This is a new printer this week - but the same issue has been happening for the past year or two with our old printer. We were hoping that replacing it after 12 years would resolve the issue; but no luck on that yet.
6. The printer is statically assigned IP 192.168.10.4 (reserved on the router as well). The DHCP pool runs from 192.168.10.5 to 192.168.10.14, with subnet mask 255.255.255.240.
7. Our network is stable and about half-and-half wired and wireless.

Does anyone know what might be causing this? All the drivers and firmware are up to date within the past few days.

To answer a comment below:
I set up DHCP because my phone and laptop move back and forth between home and work daily, and need to connect on the Wi-Fi automatically on those two different networks without a static IP address.

Comment: That's important info that needs to be added to the question. Why exactly do you bother with DHCP leases (point 6)?

Comment: @Albin: Because my kids and step-kids drop by from time to time; and that way neither I nor they need to figure out how to statically assign their phones a static IP address ***just*** for the duration of their stay. The same for when I take my phone and laptop to work and bring them back home.

Comment: That's not what I meant, why do you think this (now point 4) is relevant to your problem? Changing DHCP leases won't help if the IP in question is static and outside the DHCP range.

Answer (score 0):

Does the router report which wireless clients are currently connected to the router? If it does, does the router "see" the printer when it goes invisible?

It might be that some part of the printer's firmware that handles the wireless networking is crashing, causing the printer to drop out of the network (without updating the information shown by the printer's status displays) until some watchdog routine restarts it. If that is the cause, a firmware update to the printer might help.

The latest available firmware version seems to be V01.28, dated 05.06.22. The firmware description says it fixes a buffer overflow in the printer's networking code, so it might be relevant.

Go to https://www.usa.canon.com/support/p/imageclass-mf451dw then click on "Software & Drivers", select your OS version, then scroll down, clicking on "Load More" if necessary, until you find the most recent version of "MF455dw/ MF453dw/ MF452dw/ MF451dw Firmware Update Tool".

Read the instructions carefully before applying the update: a failed firmware update has a chance of "bricking" a device.